# Composite key mapping JPA+Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I'm having problems with the relationship between entities in a project, where all entities have the primary key composed of 3 fields;

```
Product(**ck_del, cod_empresa, codigo**, description, cod_group, cod_tax);
Group(**ck_del, cod_empresa, codigo**, description);
Tax(**ck_del, cod_empresa, codigo**, description);

//Mapping in the entity PRODUCT
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="COD_GROUP" , referencedColumnName="CODIGO")
private Group group;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="COD_TAX" , referencedColumnName="CODIGO")
private Tax tax;
```

When I try to map the entity entity with the other two entities only by the field Code of each entity returns the error:

> referencedColumnNames(CODIGO) of models.Product.group referencing models.Group not mapped to a single property

Probably because the primary group key is compounded, is there any way to do this relationship without having to change the entity's primary keys?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x4199.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

**Problem:**

Like you predicted in your question the problem comes from the fact that your Entity `Id` is composed from three `columns` and you are referencing it by only one in the `ManyToOne` relationship, in the `@JoinColumn` annotation.

**Solution:**

So you don't have to change your Entity primary key, but you should reference  three joining columns instead of one in your `ManyToOne` mapping.

You should change it in both relationships from:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="COD_TAX" , referencedColumnName="CODIGO")
private Tax tax;
```

To the following:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumns({
    @JoinColumn(name="COD_TAX" , referencedColumnName="CODIGO"),
    @JoinColumn(name="CK_DEL" , referencedColumnName="CK_DEL"),
    @JoinColumn(name="CODE_EMPRESA", referencedColumnName="CODE_EMPRESA")
    })
private Tax tax;
```

Comment: The problem is that the relationship is done only by reference COD_GROUP + COD_EMPRESA
The CK_DEL ATTRIBUTE is common to all entities and is unique for each record of each table

Comment: @BrunoC. so if it's *common to all entities* why would you used in the primary key?

Comment: Need the ck_del column as key to maintain registry integrity

Comment: Insert an image of the data arrangement in the database:
[link Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x4199.jpg)

Comment: Well to summarize things here, all the primary key fields should be used as join columns in the relationship mapping.